# Como eu altero pelo vba a altura de uma imagem no powerpoint SEM alterar a largura?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, imagem, powerpoint

No meu código eu faço assim para deixar a largura da minha imagem igual a do slide, porém dessa forma altera a altura proporcionalmente, e eu não quero isso.

```
'Criar Slide 2 

Set ppSlide = Apr.Slides.Add(2, ppLayoutBlank) 

ppSlide.Select

Planilha1.Range("c3").CurrentRegion.CopyPicture

ppSlide.Shapes.Paste

Set ppShape = ppSlide.Shapes(1)

ppShape.Width = Apr.PageSetup.SlideWidth
```

Alguém sabe como resolver isso? E se eu faço embaixo uma linha de código usando .Height, ele sobrepõe as medidas da anterior, então não resolve também

Answer (score 0):

Oi, Felipe!

Por padrão a trava de proporções está habilitada para todo objeto do tipo Imagem.

A dificuldade é que para formas geométricas não está (o que gera a confusão), e pra piorar ambos são chamados internamente de Shapes.

Acaba que não fica muito intuitivo.

Pra fazer o que você quer, precisa destravar as proporções primeiro

```
ppShape.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
ppShape.Width = Apr.PageSetup.SlideWidth
```

Entretanto vale a pena lembrar que proporção é uma coisa séria, portanto via de regra nunca deve ser distorcida se o original está correto.

Segunda situação sobre proporção, tudo pode ser reduzido sem perder qualidade (Áudio, Imagem e Vídeo), mas nada pode ser aumentado sem perder qualidade ou distorcer (exceto vetores PNG Corel e etc)

Na dúvida, evite